# Replacing Implicitly-Deleted Operator With Template Method

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo { public:
    int const i;
    Foo() : i(0) {}
};

void test() {
    Foo       a;
    Foo const b;
    a = b; //Failure here; `Foo::operator=` implicitly deleted
}
```

The indicated line fails because the `operator=` ordinarily generated by the compiler cannot be generated: `.i` is marked `const`.  This is good and expected.

The programmer can generate their own `operator=`, so long as it does not change `.i`.  E.g. this method does nothing:

```
Foo& operator=(Foo const& other) { 
    return *this;
}
```

But now, suppose I want to be more-general.  I templatize the method:

```
template <typename TypeOther>
Foo& operator=(TypeOther const& other) {
    return *this;
}
```

Suddenly, I get back the original failing behavior (tested Clang, GCC, and MSVC)!  It seems that, even though the default `operator=` is not generated, it participates in overload resolution and therefore is selected instead of the `template` variant.

1. **Why is  the implicit operator is being selected even though it does not exist (i.e, is it as if I had just written and deleted it myself—that is, it exists but is forbidden)?**
2. **How I can work around this to make my template `operator=` be selected for any type?**

Comment: *" does not exist"* - Is the wrong frame of mind. It does exist, as deleted (`= delete;` is in fact a definition). It's overload resolution choosing a deleted function that causes an error. That's how the standard defines it.